# how to set the title of a subview from a uitableviewcell selection

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a navigation app that has a section where you define your search parameters that is basically a uitableview of custom cells that do different things (uitextview, switches and labels)

What I am wanting to do is when the user selects a cell from the tableview it opens a new uitableview, when that view opens it will send a request to my database via php and get an xml response that will fill the table of that view. However I only want to use one uitableview for a few different cell selections in the previous view.I am wanting to know if I am able to specify the title of the subview when the a parentviews cell is selected.

I hope that explains what I am trying to achieve... If this is not the way for doing things could you let me know.. but from what I have been doing I think it is the correct way for doing things.

**Update
I am now trying to figure out how to define the title based off which cell was pressed, I am trying to do something like this..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

     SearchResponseTableViewController *searchResponseTableViewController = [[SearchResponseTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchResponseTableViewController" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:searchResponseTableViewController animated:YES];
    if (indexPath = 1,3) { //<<--- not sure what to do here or if its possible
        searchResponseTableViewController.title = @"manufacture";
    }
     [searchResponseTableViewController release];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: before you push the view in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you specify the title, which is a property of the view controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   //...
   SubViewController *controller = [[SubViewController alloc] init]; 
   controller.title = @"Whatever";
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: would I used an if (section = 0), if(indexPath.row == 2) etc to specify a different controller.title for the different cells?

Comment: how could I use indexpath to define different titles depending on the new view?

Comment: Right, that's why I put `//...`. You would check the `indexPath` and assign the appropriate title.